# Error using numba-scipy and numba-special extensions

Tags: python, python-3.7, numba

I try to run code example listed at page of numba-special package https://pypi.org/project/numba-special/#description

```
import numba
import scipy.special as sc
import numba_special  # The import generates Numba overloads for special
@numba.njit
def gamma_plus_1(x):
     return sc.gamma(x) + 1.0

gamma_plus_1(5.0)
```

And got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Enot/PycharmProjects/GPU-DL/test_tweezer.py", line 17, in <module>
  import numba_special  # The import generates Numba overloads for special
File "C:\Users\Enot\PycharmProjects\GPU-DL\venv\lib\site-packages\numba_special\__init__.py", line 745, in <module>
  from . import numba_overloads
File "C:\Users\Enot\PycharmProjects\GPU-DL\venv\lib\site-packages\numba_special\numba_overloads.py", line 7, in <module>
  from . import function_pointers
File "numba_special/function_pointers.pyx", line 2, in init numba_special.function_pointers
  #cython: language_level=3
TypeError: C function scipy.special.cython_special.__pyx_fuse_1bdtr has wrong signature (expected double (long, long, double, int __pyx_skip_dispatch), got double (double, long, double, int __pyx_skip_dispatch))
```

Windows 7;
python 3.7;

scipy 1.5.1;
numba 0.50.1;
numpy-scipy 0.2.0;
numba-special 0.2.0;

Visual Studio 2019;
MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v 14.26);
Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0)

How to fix this error?

Thank You.

Comment: This problem is related to that https://github.com/numba/numba-scipy/issues/35 (recent changes in scipy). The way to implement scipy-special that does not work on complex numbers can be found here https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3086 If you want scipy.special functions that deal with complex numbers this would be a workaround to get them running https://github.com/person142/numba_special/issues/1